# carrierwave cache multiple files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I use Carrierwave with Rails 5. I need to upload multiple images to some instance. But if validation is getting failed all images lost. I found and use `image_cache` for caching uploaded file, but it works only for single file upload.

Is in Carrierwave way to cache multiple files for multiple files upload.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED for Rails 5.1.4, Carrierwave 1.2.1

I did it without `attr_accesor :images`

in view:

```
= f.file_field :images, multiple: true
= f.hidden_field :images_cache
```

in controller:

```
def create
  @instance = Model.new(permited_parameters)
  add_images
  ..........
  @instance.save
end

private

def permited_parameters
  params.require(:model_name).permit(..., ..., :images_cache)
end

def add_images
  new_images = params.dig(:model_name, :images) ||
               params.dig(:model_name, :images).presence &&
               JSON.parse(params.dig(:model_name, :images))
  if new_images
    images = @instance.images
    images += new_images
    @instance.images = images
  end
end
```

The problem was in cached data type. Cached data locates as `[Array] as JSON`

Comment: do you have your sample up on github you can share please? I tried your solution and I'm getting ...unexpected keyword_if, expecting ')'

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember in which project I used it. But I suggest you use has_many polymorphic association for attachments

Comment: ok thanks, I have just added images_cache as a hidden field in the Post form and also in the Posts controller's strong parameters and it seems working for me